# Modified version of SubsetSum

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, turing-machines

Let $L=\{(y_1,...,y_n,S,p)\  |\ \exists I\subset[n]\  s.t. \ |I|=p.\ \sum_{i\in I}y_i=S\}$.

and $\forall\ 1\leq i\leq n\  :y_i \text{ is a positive integer}$,

Assuming $\mathcal{P}\neq\mathcal{NP}$.

Determine whether the following language is in $\mathcal{P}$ or not.

Comment: I've the distinct impression that this is a homework assignment or something along those lines so I feel uncomfortable giving a complete solution. That said, try reducing SumSet to it.

Comment: This is how I'm interpreting your post. In SubsetSum, we are looking for a subset that sums to S. In the case of L, we are looking for a subset of size p that sums to S. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: $\mathcal{Yes}$

Comment: This is the general idea. Suppose L is in P. Let $B(y_1,...,y_n, S, p)$ be the algorithm that decides L in polynomial time. You can construct the following algorithm A to decide SubsetSum in polynomial time by calling B with $p=1,2,...,n$. Since B runs in polynomial time, calling it n times means A still runs in polynomial time. So, if L is in P, SubsetSum would also be in P.  But we know SubSetSum is in NP, so L must also be in NP. I will let you write the formal proof.